# Scala AWS SDK S3 authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there's a topic related to this type of question but there's no solution for my problem.

I'm trying to fetch a file from an s3 bucket using AWS sdk.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.2.1"
```

The code:

```
val accessKey = ""
val secretKey = ""
val bucketName = ""

val urlPrefix = "https://s3-eu-north-1.amazonaws.com"
val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
val client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
client.setEndpoint("s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com")
client.getObject(bucketName, "test.txt")
```

Keys have been removed for security reasons. The code fails at the last line with:

> [AmazonS3Exception: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.]

I've been struggling with it for the whole day. Setting an endpoint also did not help me. It works with python's boto3 so there's no problem with my credentials.

Comment: you should use the v4 signature to connect v4 s3.

Comment: I think 1.2.1 should use sigv4 automatically but if not you can use this https://github.com/ticofab/aws-request-signer

Answer (score 0):

Try use Amazon V2 SDK for java. I'we worked with Minio self-hosted instance with both SDK's and just switching to newer version helped to avoid this error. Also we used custom region.

In my build.gradle:

`implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.18.24'`

```
@Singleton
public class S3Service {

    @Value("${s3.bucket}")
    private String s3bucket;

    @Value("${s3.host}")
    private String s3host;

    @Value("${s3.user}")
    private String s3user;

    @Value("${s3.password}")
    private String s3pass;

    public String getBucket() {
        return this.s3bucket;
    }

    public S3Client getClient() {
        final StaticCredentialsProvider creds = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(
            s3user,
            s3pass
        ));
        return S3Client.builder()
            .endpointOverride(URI.create(s3host))
            .forcePathStyle(true)
            .region(Region.of("my-company"))
            .credentialsProvider(creds)
            .build();

    }
}
```